# Where does Chrome Devtools store the results of my websites analysis?

Tags: google-chrome, web, browser, google-chrome-extension, visual-web-developer

I want to save my analysis results of my websites. Where does Devtools stored this information?
Updated with the screenshot.

[Devtools interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JepDf.png)

Comment: What is your goal in asking this question? Are you thinking the data is stored to a file and you want to be able to access the file? Are you wanting to know where in the data structures Chrome uses within RAM this is stored? Are you wanting to access this data programmatically?

Comment: My project as follow, I built my website and mobile app. my mobile app has webview that renders my websites. So,  I  analysed my webview by using remote debugging through USB.So, I think, the data is stored to a file somewhere on my machine.  I just wonder where the file is on my machine

Comment: Please edit the question and show an example of that data, maybe a screenshot.